# Android - Memory leak when dynamically building UI with image resource backgrounds

Tags: java, android, memory-management, memory-leaks, virtual-machine

I have an Activity that I swear is leaking memory.  The app I'm working on does a lot with images, so I've had to be pretty stingy with memory when working directly with Bitmaps.  I added an Activity, and now if you use this new Activity it basically puts me over the edge with mem usage and I end up throwing the "Bitmap exceeds VM budget" exception.  If you never launch this Activity, everything is smooth as it was previously.

I started reading about memory leaks, and I think that I have a similar situation to what is described in the article in the Android docs.  I'm dynamically creating a bunch of image views and adding a BackgroundDrawable from the resources and adding an OnClickListener as well.  I imagine I have to do some cleanup when the Activity hits onPause in its life cycle, but I'd like to know specifically what is the correct way.

Here is the code that should demonstrate the objects I'm working with...

```
    LinearLayout templateContainer;
    .
    .
    .
    ImageView imgTemplatePreview = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.imgTemplatePreview);
    .
    .
    .
    imgTemplatePreview.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(previewId));
    imgTemplatePreview.setOnClickListener(imgClick);
    templateContainer.addView(item);
```

Comment: have you since found any other information on this topic? I'm working with a single view that flips images after button is clicked, and after multiple restarts of the app it is evident something is going on behind the scenes because I used unbind() method and it still OOM on me due to bitmap size exceeding...

Comment: Yeah...this was posted 7 months ago, and I've come a looong way with my understanding of Bitmaps, memory, OOM errors, etc.  Find my email through my profile and I'd gladly discuss, because it's way too much information for a comments thread.  In short, when I'm really pushing the limits, I write a class that manages my bitmaps (in some cases, multiple classes) and I recycle every bitmap when I'm done using it.  This could be as simple as just keeping a single Bitmap in your activity and calling .recycle before replacing it with a new instance.  Find me if needed, I'm happy to discuss more.

Comment: Hi Rich, I realize we're all busy and sharing knowledge takes time but I too would really appreicate some more indepth description on what you've gathered in these 7 months as I'm still at month 2 ;) Perhaps a blog link would be really popular article as it seems a reoccuring question.  I've read the excellent Romain's article but that seems to be only hint of what we need to know about what causes leaks when handling bitmaps... the .recycle  and onClick callbacks causing leaks weren't mentioned there so certain there other other tips & tricks being missed by the masses.  Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Rich,

If you are going to be dealing with that many `Bitmap`s you should aggressively clean them up when they are not needed (`onPause` is a good start).

I remember a discussion from a long time ago about `ImageView`s and their odd behavior with lingering references to their displayed bitmaps. From what I do recall is that you should remove all references to the current context from the ImageView if you are going to keep the layout alive but don't want to leak. Remove the onClick listener and bitmap. Call `.recycle()` on the `Bitmap` if you want to aggressively free memory. Make sure you don't have any static fields with lingering references to the context or inner class references to it.

The code for Android's launcher was also mentioned during this as a good reference where they do some of these things. OpenSource is your friend.

EDIT

Found Romain Guys article. Basicly he mentions this part of the way though

> This example is one of the simplest cases of leaking the Context and you can see how we worked around it in the Home screen’s source code (look for the unbindDrawables() method) by setting the stored drawables’ callbacks to null when the activity is destroyed.

Now I've never had to manage this type of memory usage (yet) so from here I suggest looking at [The Home Screen Source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Launcher.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/launcher/LauncherModel.java;h=0ef2a806b767142b28b2ff3b37f21f4ca16c355d;hb=cupcake) for more details. You'll find their `unbind()` method on line 620

Comment: So, that's exactly my question.  When adding a background via setBackgroundDrawable and an OnClickListener via setOnClickListener, what is the proper way to clean up those resources.  I understand the concept that I need to clean them up, and any explicit Bitmaps I instantiate in my code are all getting cleaned up already.  The question is - how do I PROPERLY clean up stuff attached to a View-derived UI element

Comment: @Rich Found the article I was thinking of while writing this answer. Its by Romain Guy (Google Android Engineer) so its some really good stuff. http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/

Comment: I gave you the upvote because it helped and you provided valuable info, but I'm actually looking for a more in depth discussion about how the high level View objects handle their resources internally and what bugs and/or idiosyncrasies exist that would require the dev to do additional manual cleanup.  If I accept your answer, no one will discuss this further. You provided good info, but it's the same thing I found when googling, and doesn't fully answer my question.  I accept correct answers, and I'm generous with the upvotes...you don't have to ask.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to sound a little odd, but I have had trouble with apps that did any bitmap manipulation on a thread other than the one associated with the Handler for your Activity.  In particular, I had an app that was leaking a lot of memory by doing image manipulation in a java.util.Timer thread.  When I migrated that code over to using Handler.postDelayed, the memory issues cleared themselves up.

Comment: I hear you, but the question was more along the lines of what to do with the high level Android View objects to maximize their memory usage and not leak there.  I have a mountain of image manipulation code that's already working fine.  There's a definite limit to what you can load at once, but in normal working conditions, I've fine tuned that stuff plenty and it works just fine.  As soon as I introduce the stuff mentioned above...BOOM!

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm afraid I don't have much to offer other than sympathy.  I've worked on a couple of apps that had pretty complex UIs, and after a certain point, we just hit the limit of what BitmapFactory could handle and we just had to scale things back.  On one app, I had to resort to doing some pagination to make things work for my app, and in another, I had to reduce the size of a bunch of graphic elements.