# Repeating 6 bitmas taken from drawable on map causes out of memory error

Tags: android, bitmap

I already tried to find a solution to my problem in this and in some other sites but with no luck. I have a map (Google map V2) set on my app. This map is full of markers (around 450) and each marker has an icon set from a drawable file. The drawable files are in total 6 so there are about 450 markers repeating 6 drawables (each different icon refers to a location on the map). When I first launch the map, there are no problems and everything works fine. But if I go back to the previous screen and launch again the map, the app crashes with an out of memory error. I think the problem is due to the fact that the system is keeping in memory all the bitmaps, with an incredible waste of resources, seen that the drawables are only six.

I tried to reference the bitmaps to the application context as suggested [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) with no good results. Is there an easy way to solve this issue?

Line 324:

```
if (IDTipologia.get(i).equals("1")) {
            setLoghino(R.drawable.chieseluoghidiculto);
            //iconcina = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE);
            Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(),
                    R.drawable.markerchiese);
            iconcina = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon);
}
```

ad so on until the 6th drawable.

Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(10990): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(10990): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
E/AndroidRuntime(10990):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreateFromParcel(Native   Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10990):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.access$000(Bitmap.java:28)
E/AndroidRuntime(10990):    at android.graphics.Bitmap$1.createFromParcel(Bitmap.java:1052)
E/AndroidRuntime(10990):    at android.graphics.Bitmap$1.createFromParcel(Bitmap.java:1044)
E/AndroidRuntime(10990):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.internal.IBitmapDescriptorFactoryDelegate$Stub.onTransact(IBitmapDescriptorFactoryDelegate.java:101)
E/AndroidRuntime(10990):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:297)
E/AndroidRuntime(10990):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.h$a$a.a(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(10990):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(10990):    at it.eventitrapani.appaeventitp.ElencoMappaTutteCoseDaVedere.addMarkersToMap(ElencoMappaTutteCoseDaVedere.java:324)
E/AndroidRuntime(10990):    at it.eventitrapani.appaeventitp.ElencoMappaTutteCoseDaVedere.setUpMap(ElencoMappaTutteCoseDaVedere.java:269)
E/AndroidRuntime(10990):    at it.eventitrapani.appaeventitp.ElencoMappaTutteCoseDaVedere.setUpMapIfNeeded(ElencoMappaTutteCoseDaVedere.java:257)
E/AndroidRuntime(10990):    at it.eventitrapani.appaeventitp.ElencoMappaTutteCoseDaVedere.onCreate(ElencoMappaTutteCoseDaVedere.java:208)
E/AndroidRuntime(10990):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
E/AndroidRuntime(10990):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
E/AndroidRuntime(10990):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
E/AndroidRuntime(10990):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
E/AndroidRuntime(10990):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
E/AndroidRuntime(10990):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
E/AndroidRuntime(10990):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(10990):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(10990):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
E/AndroidRuntime(10990):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10990):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(10990):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
E/AndroidRuntime(10990):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
E/AndroidRuntime(10990):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It's still unclear from the question/code: Are you reusing the Bitmaps or are you decoding a new one each time you create a marker?

Comment: I'm decoding a new one for each marker, how can I reuse them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why are you loading your bitmaps from resources like that? You can get a `Drawable` directly from your resources `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blah)`. If you retrieve the Drawable like that, they will all share the underlying Bitmap, so there would only be N (where N is the number of marker icons you have) bitmaps loaded in memory.

Now, if you are applying some transformation to the drawable you might need to call `mutate()` on it first to get a new Drawable with a separate state (otherwise if you make one transparent ALL of them will become transparent).

**Update:**
Solution was to use the marker icon initialization that uses a resource ID instead of a bitmap directly:

```
markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow)));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your kind reply first of all. Well I retrieve the drawable like that, because the marker of the Google map needs an icon in bitmap format, and it's not possible to assign the drawable directly to the marker. I don't do any transformations to those drawables, I just have 6 different categories of markers and about 450 locations (churches, monuments, museums, beaches, archeological sites and natural parks) and I would like the appropriate icon to appear on each marker. It works fine the first time, the second time it goes out of memory.

Comment: Untrue, you can use a drawable: `markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow)));`. It's right there in the examples in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#add_a_marker)

Comment: What a bad thing is ignorance! Thank you very much! You solved my problem!

Comment: `getResources().getDrawable` causes a memory leak

Comment: @Siddharth uuuhh.. Citation needed?

Comment: Citation : I am facing the same issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651366/android-memory-leak-when-dynamically-building-ui-with-image-resource-backgroun

Comment: What I meant is, where did you read that "getResources().getDrawable()" causes a memory leak? Most "memory leaks" related to images in Android are NOT memory leaks, just big images. I think it's quite rash to blame `getDrawable()` without you even saying what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to add a overlay on a mapactivity. This memory just keeps building, and the only allocation I isolated it to was getResources.getDrawable() call. I am facing this issue now. I believe that this answer is incorrect. Now, if I prove my self incorrect, I will gladly reverse the vote.